# Table with Merged Cells

Tags: support, feature-request

Currently there is not way to have:

1. Tables
2. Merged cells in tables

Currently there does not seam to be a way to do tables than draw tables other than image links or character by character drawring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, that is so.

The topic [Is there any markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/139866) is tagged 'status-declined'.

Comment: Ah there are markdown extensions and also aciidoc also supports it. I guess this is a feature that might not be implemented after all. I guess images might be good enough.

Comment: Topics (like this one) will keep jumping to the top of the 'Active' view every so often, until or unless they are accepted or deleted (or maybe, upvoted).